Should we have a [tag:rce]?
Since the site scope isn't limited to reverse code engineering as such, would it make sense to have a specific tag for questions regarding the reverse engineering of code in particular? I.e. something like rce?!

When anyone says reverse engineering, pretty much everyone's thoughts jump straight to rce. We should have a ree(electrical), rme(mechanical), and so forth as well.

@MMavipc: or similar to another this topic have only the ones you mentioned, instead of the implied "default" (in the linked question "user-mode" is that "default"). Mind to write up your comment as an answer? You can use [tag:something] as markup (or rather markdown) for tags the way I did in my question above.

In my opinion, whenever anyone mentions "Reverse Engineering," everyone's thoughts jump straight to reverse code engineering. RCE should be implied, unless there are other tags such as ree for electrical, rme for mechanical, and so on.
